# How can I set a breakpoint in the source code of a windows driver I'm debugging remotely

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, remote-debugging

I've made a lot of progress knowing nothing about kernel development on windows: I can attach the vs2015 debugger to the remote target, and when I click break-all, the remote machine freezes, and I can see the 4 cpus in my thread list. I can load the symbols from the ms symbol server, and from the local copy I've made of the debug build pdbs of my kernel driver.
But how do I actually attach the source code I have locally to the remotely running machine?

There's some tie-in that I'm missing. I copied the pdbs and source of the driver locally figuring the remote machine is frozen and can't access the filesystem. Maybe I'm wrong there.

But either way, I'm not sure what the mechanism is to find the source code that the kernel is running for the driver and browse through it in visual studio. I've never used windbg before either so references to that won't help me.

I've googled and googled and all the information I found got me to where I can attach and run windbg commands in the immediate window, but I'm not getting the last bit where I connect source code to the client side of the debugger so I can set a break point.

Any ideas? pointers to web pages with this magical information?

Thanks.

Comment: The source files should definitely be on your local machine (not the target). Have you read the VS docs on how it locates source files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx

Comment: so I looked that over and it's geared towards userspace debugging, not kernel debugging, but I did it all anyway, and no change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work. I think it was more a matter of lining things up better.
I copied all the source and pdbs from the target server to the same set of paths on my debugger/client machine. Pointed all the symbolpaths to the local location, fired up the debugger (or rather, attached) did a simple file->open on the source file, added a breakpoint, triggered the code on the target machine and voila! The debugger stopped on the breakpoint.
Not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday but copying the paths to their identical locations seemed to have clicked all the pieces together for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
After you are able to build and deploy the driver:
in VS click on debug and attach to Target
Click on pause so you can enter debug commands
Enter the following commands:

> .srcpath+ (Path to your source code)
>
> .sympath+ (Path to your .pdb file; usually with the .sys)

Now open your source code and place a break point somewhere and note the line.
Go back to the debug command window and enter bl to list the break points.
These break points should now show up in the list.

Here is a link to a good step by step example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers---step-by-step-lab--echo-kernel-mode-